# flip numpy array along one dimension

Tags: python, numpy

what's the numpy equivalent of the following function:

```
def customized_mirror(in_array):
    
    out_array = np.zeros((N, N, N))
    for idx in range(N):
        out_array[:, :, idx] = in_array[:, :, N-1-idx]

return out_array
```

I've tried all combinations of `np.flip` and did not get the expected, mirrored array.

Comment: you should have tagged `numpy`... -- I suppose you don't know what a stride of -1 does? you must have missed some combinations of `np.flip` because [documentation says](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html): `flip(m, n)` corresponds to `m[...,::-1,...]` with `::-1` at position n.

Answer (score 1):

```
out_array = in_array[:,:,::-1]
```

or

```
out_array = in_array[:,:,::-1].copy()
```

The first will cause `out_array` to contain the same actual data array as `in_array`, but with different indexing into the same data.  The latter will copy it.